# What does "<<" (double angle brackets) mean in C/C++ enum?

Tags: c++, c

```
enum ofp10_port_state {

    OFPPS10_STP_LISTEN  = 0 << 8, /* Not learning or relaying frames. */
    OFPPS10_STP_LEARN   = 1 << 8, /* Learning but not relaying frames. */
    OFPPS10_STP_FORWARD = 2 << 8, /* Learning and relaying frames. */
    OFPPS10_STP_BLOCK   = 3 << 8, /* Not part of spanning tree. */
    OFPPS10_STP_MASK    = 3 << 8  /* Bit mask for OFPPS10_STP_* values. */

};
```

Comment: It's the left bit-shift operator. That should give a hint.

Comment: It is a bit shift operator. Has nothing to do with enums.

Comment: This has to be a duplicate...and general reference...

Comment: @NominSim I agree, but I looked for several minutes and couldn't find one specifically for C or C++ ... blasted trying to search for "<<" on SO. (The questions with "bit shift" in them tend to be much more focused...)

Comment: (It's generally best to try an appropriate search first; even though I can't find a "duplicate" on SO, looking for "C C++ operators" in a standard web-search would yield many useful results. E.g. To find out what `+` or `%` meant, where would one look? Same place -- the operator section in a reference.)

Comment: It's a basic operator. Please refer to some C/C++ books.

Answer (score 9):

Its a left bit shift operator. Meaning it shifts the bits left the indicated number of bits:

say that the value is:

```
0x0F or 00001111
0x0F << 4 = 0xF0 or 11110000
```

In microsoft c++ shifts right (>>) keep the sign (or the most significant digit, the one on the far left) depending on if the number is signed or unsigned

(assuming size of a byte):

```
signed integer (an int for example):
0x80 or 10000000
0x80 >> 7 = 11111111
0x10 or 00010000
0x10 >> 4 = 00000001
if its unsigned (a uint):
0x80 or 10000000
0x80 >> 7 = 00000001
0x10 or 00010000
0x10 >> 4 = 00000001
```

Answer (score 6):

`<<` is a left bitshift operator.

If you have a bit pattern like `0010` (2 in decimal) and shift it to the left by 2 like so `0010<<2`, you get `1000` (8 in decimal).

An enum is simply an integer that is large enough to hold at least an `int`. Thus we can directly assign `int` values like 0, 1, etc. to it.

In this case, we are assigning things like `1 << 8` to it (which yields `100000000` or 256 in decimal).